# Shadowing in without "let"

Tags: rust, shadowing

From my understanding, shadowing in Rust allows you to use the same variable by using `let` and re-declaring the variable e.g.

```
let x = 5;

let x = x + 1;

let x = x * 2;

println!("The value of x is: {}", x);
```

but, if you make the variable mutable, doesn't that mimic shadowing e.g.:

```
let mut x = 5;
println!("The value of x is: {}", x);
x = 6;
println!("The value of x is: {}", x);
 x = 7;
println!("The value of x is: {}", x);
```

In example 1 & 2, where is the variable stored, in the stack or heap?

Comment: It is preferred to post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question as well as others hunting for one of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values in your example are stored on the stack. In example 1, a new value is pushed onto the stack for each `let` statement.

It looks like you got the example from [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html#shadowing). Maybe read this paragraph again for emphasis:

> The other difference between `mut` and shadowing is that because we’re
>   effectively creating a new variable when we use the `let` keyword again,
>   we can change the type of the value but reuse the same name.

Comment: so its creating new variables? what about 2? if its meant to be mututable then by definition its type isnt fixed at compile time so heap?

Comment: In example 2  there is only 1 variable on the stack. Its value is changed with each assignment.

Comment: @Data_Kid "if its meant to be mututable then by definition its type isnt fixed" What is your definition of mutability that that would follow from the definition? Mutable variables still have a fixed type in Rust (and the vast majority of other statically typed languages).